# Why I am getting different output when accessing inner function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, memoization

Here is my code

```
function first() {
  
  console.log("first")
  
  return function second() { return console.log("second") }
}

let foo = first() // It is outputing "first" once

foo() // Output is "second"
first()() // Output is "first" "second"
```

What I do not understand is why `foo()` is giving a different output comparing to `first()()`. If `foo` = `first()`, then I think it should have the same output.

The second question (and less important) is: how can I avoid the output when assigning the variable `let foo = first()`  ?

Comment: Because "First" has already been logged to the console, when you assigned foo to the result of first()

Comment: `first()` is _calling_ `first`. You're executing the code in that function, which includes the `console.log`... `()` isn't "access". It's "Run this".

Comment: it's High order function which is a function that return a function or a function that takes a function as an argument,when u do first()() you invoke the first function and the second function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are not *assigning* `first` to `foo` when you do `first()`, you are *calling* `first`. When `first` is called, it logs `"first"` to the console and then it returns the function `second`. So `foo` gets assigned the *return value* of `first` which is the function `second`.

**Assigning first to foo**

You can assign the function `first` to `foo` via normal assignment without calling it:

```
let foo = first; // now foo === first
```

**Assigning the returned function `second` to foo**

```
let foo = first(); // note the use of (); now foo === second
```

**Immediately calling the returned function**

In the last line, you are doing two things in one line. The first `first()` (no pun intended) returns the `second` function (and thereby executes the `console.log` statement) which is *immediately called* via `()` (and executes the other `console.log` statement). That's why you see it logging `"first"`*and* `"second"`.

```
let foo = first()(); // note the doubled use of (); now, foo === undefined
```

---

**Whatever are we doing here?**

Although it might seem a bit strange at first, the technique of passing and/or returning a function to/from another function is very useful - so much that it has a name: Higher Order Function (or - as I like to call it - HOF).
One pretty common example of a HOF is `Array.prototype.map`. When you pass a function to `.map`, it projects the function onto every element in the array and collects the resulting value of each projection into a new array which it finally returns.

A concrete example of a HOF besides `.map`: Suppose you have to call `.split` on different input strings that come from different sources but you always want to split the strings on the same character. Create a `makeSplitter` HOF:

```
function makeSplitter(splitOn) {      // <-- HOF
  return function (inputString) {     // <-- return value of HOF
    return inputString.split(splitOn);
  }
}
```

With this, you can create a general function that splits an input string, say, by slash:

```
const splitSlashes = makeSplitter(/\//g);
```

You can think of `splitSlashes` as if it had been written like so:

```
const splitSlashes = function (inputString) {
  return inputString.split(/\//g);
}
```

And now you can use that to split various strings that contain slashes into separate parts:

```
 console.log(splitSlashes('08/12/2022')); // logs ['08', '12', '2022']
 console.log(splitSlashes('www.example.com/path/to/x/')); // logs ['www.example.com', 'path', 'to', 'x']
```

If you need another function that - for example - splits a string on `.`, just use `makeSplitter` with another argument:

```
const splitDots = makeSplitter(/\./g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Output of a function is a **value in return statement** but not console.log in a function body

```js
function first() {
  return function second() { return 'second' }
}

let foo = first() //now a function is in foo variable

foo() // "second"
first()() // "second"
```

the same output in both cases

Comment: You are correct. It is not an output but a side effect. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: np!,yeap, exactly